Card with both a gradient background and gradient border with rounded corners in CSS?
I'm trying to create a card with both a gradient background inside and a gradient border around it, while maintaining rounded corners. The gradient background is working fine, but I'm struggling to make the gradient border work with the rounded corners.
Here's my current code:
.testimonial-card {
  border: double 1px transparent;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff20, #000),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #000);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}

I also tried using the border-image property to create the gradient border, but the border-radius doesn't work properly with it, and there are some browser compatibility issues.
See The Card Layout
How can I achieve both a gradient background and a gradient border with rounded corners in CSS?

why double? use solid

I used that, but didn't work. there are two linear gradients in the bg-image. But it was affecting the background. I need white color border and dark color gradient bg.

it works fine with solid: https://jsfiddle.net/v41wqL5u/1/ (I changed the color so you can better see)

Can you please make it like the image I attached?
When I change the color, I don't see the expected output
